# CSS nested lists into multiple columns

Tags: css, html, html-lists, nested-lists

I would like to display nested lists in columns, as is frequently used in page footers.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Header 1 
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Header 2 
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1.2</li>
            <li>Item 2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I'd like the result to look like:

```
Header 1         Header 2
Item 1           Item 1.2
Item 2           Item 2.2
```

I have been playing with `display:inline` and `display:block` for a while and cannot get it to show up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
<ul>
    <li style="float:left;">
        Header 1 
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li style="float:left;">
        Header 2 
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1.2</li>
            <li>Item 2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Picked this one as the most concise example of correct element to use.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses the "oh, so cool" display: inline-block;
http://jsfiddle.net/b9MWz/4/

```
ul{
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none; /*remove bullets*/
}

ul li{    
   display: inline-block;
    width: 20%; /*or whatever unit*/

}

ul li ul, ul li ul li{
    display: static;
    width: 100%;

}
```

and a solution that uses float:
http://jsfiddle.net/8F8Uy/3/

```
ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none; /*remove bullets*/
}

ul li{    
    float: left;
    width: 20%; /*or whatever unit*/

}

ul li ul, ul li ul li{
    float: none; /* un-"float" */
    width: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something like below code, but there are few other ways too to achieve this, as this depends upon your page structure and final goal

1) as you have nested list and we want to target width and float property only till first children we have used '>' sign in .footer-list > li selector.

2) also you may define width in pixel or percentage for .footer-list > li . Its uptp you.

3) you may need to clear float on parent .footer-list

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> New Document </title>
<style type="text/css">

  *{
    padding:0;
    margin:0
  }

  ul li{
    list-style:none;
  }
  .footer-list{
    padding:10px;
  }
  .footer-list > li{
    /*width:300px;*/ /* you may un comment this line and comment below line width in %*/

    width:20%;
    float:left;
  }


</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="footer-list">
    <li>
        Header 1 
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Header 2 
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1.2</li>
            <li>Item 2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

hope this fits your need.

Answer (score 0):

Give to the first ul tag the class "myul"

```
<ul class="myul">
    <li>
        Header 1 ...
```

and use this css code:

```
        ul.myul{
            list-style: none;
        }
        ul.myul>li{
            float:left;
            padding-right: 30px;
        }
        ul.myul ul{
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0; 
            margin: 0;
        }
```